# GNU parallel: How to run Rscript inside a shell script

Tags: gnu-parallel

Am using latest parallel on ubuntu server, inside `tmux`

this works fine when typed on the command line:

```
parallel -j 20  --progress --halt 2   ' Rscript Run.r   {}' ::: {1..80}
```

But I wanted to run many such commands, one after the other, in a shell script and it always fails, by not passing the argument to Rscript.

Any way to make this work?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem outside tmux? Can you reproduce the problem with something else than Rscript - preferably something that others can try, too? Which shell is the script running?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in `tmux`:

```
#!/bin/bash

parallel -j 20 --progress --halt 2 'sleep {}' ::: {1..80}
parallel -j 20 --progress --halt 2 'sleep {}' ::: {1..80}
parallel -j 20 --progress --halt 2 'sleep {}' ::: {1..80}
parallel -j 20 --progress --halt 2 'sleep {}' ::: {1..80}
```

Remember that {1..80} is a bash construct: It will not work in /bin/sh.

Comment: Thanks Ole, I use zsh, this did indeed work,

#!/bin/bash

parallel -j 32  --progress --halt 2   ' Rscript Run.r   {}' ::: {1..80}

and as you hint, I had #!/bin/sh, which works for all my other scripts.
I would never have figured the #!/bin/bash out.